# Advantage of storing data in EOS compared to traditional database

Tags: nodeos, transactions, eosjs, eosio.token

I am learning blockchain concept and EOS.

From my understanding, data which is stored in blockchain can not be modified. But, data in table in EOS can actually be modified?

Then what is difference between storing data in traditional database and storing them in EOS?

I might have some misunderstanding around the concept of EOS and blockchain. It will be very appreciated if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the blockchain as a **tamper resistant** database.

You interact with it per transactions that are signed and the log is signed as well. The method of **hashing hashes** (blocks) and chaining them is used for making it resistant to manipulation.

In a traditional system an attacker would be able manipulate the database and the transaction log more or less easily. For a blockchain it would be very hard to manipulate this because you would have to change the history and all following blocks. Therefore the computation time will rise very high and is therefore consider more safe.

Another point is that you have **trustless** content of the blockchain because everything is signed and is **decentralized** because everyone is looking at the same state. This is also better for **availability**.

For EOS.IO it is kind of special because it also offers to not only store data in the network, but also **use the computation power of the network** which you can rent.

Nevertheless computing this needs **more computation time** and is therefore **slower** and more expensive.

#### Pros:

- tamper resistant
- decentralized + availability
- trustless
- use data storage and computation power of the network

#### Cons:

- slower
- expensive

#### Further Information:

- [Hash/Merkle Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)
- [Byzantine Generals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you please explain how EOS achieve tamper resistant database? because data in table is mutable then how can it be tamper resistant??

Comment: The hashes/signatures would not match. You could restore the database by performing/replaying the verified transactions. Also the database is stored in several nodes, considering byzantine general problem you are save as long as the majority has the same copy. So you can easily detect changes, replay by fetching from another node (+compare) or replay the transactions. I added some links